# Enter-PSSession not working within domain

Tags: powershell, remote, windows-domain

Im sitting on two VM's where one is a server and another is the client. When I try to `Enter-PSSession` on both the server and the client, i get the following error

```
Connecting to remote server 10.10.106.2 failed with the following error 
message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication 
scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined 
to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine 
must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to 
configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might 
not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the 
following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the 
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

## Computer Details

**Server**

- OS: Windows Server 2016
- IP: 192.168.2.2
- `hostname.exe`:Host
- `$env:Username`: Administrator
- `$env:UserDomain`: JEPPESEN
- `whoami`: jeppesen\administrator
- Domain in `control.exe system`:Jeppesen.local
- Full computername in `control.exe system`: Host.Jeppesen.local
- `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion | FT -H` : 5 1 14393 2248

**Client**

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 1809
- IP: 192.168.2.3
- `hostname.exe`: DESKTOP-USJVHNQ
- `$env:Username`: JoHa
- `$env:UserDomain`: JEPPESEN
- `whoami`: jeppesen\joha
- Domain in `control.exe system`:Jeppesen.local
- Full computername in `control.exe system`: DESKTOP-USJVHNQ.Jeppesen.local
- `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion | FT -H` : 5 1 17763 1

And I've checked the Firewall. Have added TrustedHosts on both sides. Even followed a guide to configure WinRM on a domain controller.

And sorry about this long post.

Comment: What is your exact `Enter-PSSession` command and are you specifying `-Credential Domain\User`?

Comment: I've tried `Enter-PSSession 192.168.2.3 -credential Jeppesen\Adminstrator` as well as `Jeppesen.local\Administrator`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is giving you most of what you need. This isn't just about the TrustedHosts list; it's saying that in order to use an IP address with the default authentication scheme, you have to ALSO be using HTTPS (which isn't configured by default) and provide explicit credentials. I can tell you're at least not using SSL, because you didn't use the -UseSSL switch.

Note that SSL/HTTPS is not configured by default - that's an extra step you'll have to take. You can't just add -UseSSL.

The default authentication mechanism is Kerberos, and it wants to see real host names as they appear in AD. Not IP addresses, not DNS CNAME nicknames. Some folks will enable Basic authentication, which is less picky - but you should also set up HTTPS since you'd otherwise pass credentials in cleartext. Enable-PSRemoting only sets up HTTP.

Adding names to your hosts file won't work. This isn't an issue of name resolution; it's about how the mutual authentication between computers is carried out.

Additionally, if the two computers involved in this connection aren't in the same AD domain, the default authentication mechanism won't work. Read "help about_remote_troubleshooting" for information on configuring non-domain and cross-domain authentication.

From the docs at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347642.aspx

```
HOW TO USE AN IP ADDRESS IN A REMOTE COMMAND
-----------------------------------------------------
    ERROR:  The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the
    authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client
    computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used
    or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts
    configuration setting.

The ComputerName parameters of the New-PSSession, Enter-PSSession and
Invoke-Command cmdlets accept an IP address as a valid value. However,
because Kerberos authentication does not support IP addresses, NTLM
authentication is used by default whenever you specify an IP address. 

When using NTLM authentication, the following procedure is required
for remoting.

1. Configure the computer for HTTPS transport or add the IP addresses
   of the remote computers to the TrustedHosts list on the local
   computer.

   For instructions, see "How to Add a Computer to the TrustedHosts
   List" below.


2. Use the Credential parameter in all remote commands.

   This is required even when you are submitting the credentials
   of the current user.
```

So, use the hostname or configure SSL/HTTPS.